# Error al imprimir una List

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Tengo el siguiente código realizado en Netbeans el cual se encuentra conectada a una base de datos de MYSQL y me genera el siguiente error al intentar imprimir lo que retorna que son todos los datos de una consulta de una tabla llamada cursos.

Cuando imprimo lo que me retorna me sale lo siguiente:

```
[DatosVo.CursoVO@799f7e29, DatosVo.CursoVO@4b85612c, DatosVo.CursoVO@277050dc]
```

Ayuda sobre lo que se encuentra errado, gracias.

```
public List<CursoVO> ConsultarTodosLosCursos() {

        try {
            List<CursoVO> cursitos = new ArrayList();
            Conectar();
            PreparedStatement sentencia = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM curso");
            ResultSet datos = sentencia.executeQuery();
            while (datos.next()) {
                CursoVO cursito = new CursoVO();
                cursito.idCurso = datos.getInt("idCurso");
                cursito.nombre = datos.getString("nombre");
                cursito.cupo = datos.getInt("cupo");
                cursitos.add(cursito);
            }
            Desconectar();
            return cursitos;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error en el metodo. " + e);
            return null;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hola, agrega como imprimes tus objetos que se encuentran en el listado y si es posible el objeto CursoVO.

Answer (score 0):

En tu objeto `CursoVo` puedes realizar lo siguiente sobre escribir el mètodo `toString()`, definiendo que valor deseas imprimir , suponiendo que tienes un getter llamado `getNombre()` para obtener el nombre y deseas imprimir el nombre:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getNombre();
}
```